# Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I try to connect Android project to Firebase but I get this error as I added the following to pubsec.yaml:

```
firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
```

when I gradle run and it is not working

```
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :cloud_firestore_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
```

Is there any solution for it

Answer (score 132, accepted):

In your `android/app/build.gradle`, update the following:

```
android {
    // ...
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        minSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

into:

```
android {
    // ...
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        minSdkVersion 23
    }
}
```

---

**Note:**

You need to use `minSdkVersion 23` when using firebase in flutter.

From the [docs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#3):

> By default, Flutter supports Android SDK v16 (Jelly Bean, released 2012), but multidex doesn't really work with Jelly Bean (though, it's possible). Configuring Jelly Bean to work is beyond the scope of this codelab, so we'll change the minimum target SDK version from v16 to v21 (Lollipop, released 2014).

To change the minimum target SDK version:

- Open android/app/build.gradle, then find the line that says minSdkVersion 16.
- Change that line to minSdkVersion 21.
- Save the file.

---

After upgrading, it should work fine. **The `settings.gradle` file is provided to you when you create any new flutter project**. For reference, this is how your `settings.gradle` file should be (default file no changes):

```
include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

https://github.com/PeterHdd/Firebase-Flutter-tutorials/blob/master/firebase_storage_tutorial/android/settings.gradle

---

**Explanation** of `settings.gradle`:

`Gradle` is a build tool used for android projects, just like `ant` or `maven`, it uses groovy language or kotlin for scripting. In this case the above code is written using `groovy` and since `groovy` is a `jvm` language then it is able to use `Java` libraries. So basically [`include ':app'`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#include-java.lang.String...-) will add the project to the build(in groovy you can omit parenthesis for a method).

This line:

```
def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()
```

is getting the path to the flutter project that you created in your machine. For reference:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/ProjectDescriptor.html#getProjectDir--
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath--
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

This line:

```
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
```

Will create an empty file called `.flutter-plugins`, under the root of your flutter project. Then `plugins.each{ name, path ->` this is basically an iteration that will add the plugin name and the path of the plugin to the file `.flutter_plugins`, if the **plugin is not found in that file you get the error in this question**

`.flutter-plugins` file:

```
# This is a generated file; do not edit or check into version control.
cloud_firestore=/Users/<users>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.6/
cloud_firestore_web=/Users/<users>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-0.1.1+2/
firebase_auth=/Users/<users>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.16.1/
firebase_auth_web=/Users/<users>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-0.1.2/
firebase_core=/Users/<users>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.4+3/
firebase_core_web=/Users/<users>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-0.1.1+2/
firebase_database=/Users/<users>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-3.1.5/
firebase_storage=/Users/<users>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-3.1.5/
```

Comment: @GunJack you need minsdkversion 21 because firebase in flutter doesnt work with version 16, you can see here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#3.. All you have to do is create a new flutter project, the settings.gradle in the other answer is already provided to you when you create a new flutter project

Comment: An explanation on what this piece of code does will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Comment: But my settings.gradle has refrences to flutter sdk and other stuff. Should I overwrite that with the code you provided or just append?

Comment: I'm not sure wat u have in settings.gradle but this flutter_plugins file has to be created try to append to see if it works

Comment: I commented out what was in there earlier. And put these files in. Its working now without issues.

Comment: This is working. If you didnt have settings gradle file as above. replace it with above gradle settings. (Its worked for me)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 80):

Change file `settings.gradle` to this

```
include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Can you please also explain why it worked?

Comment: @BugsHappen https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2599

Comment: don't change to this, but add this to the `settings.gradle` file

Answer (score 20):

> ### Please add this in flutter app -> android -> settings.gradle

```
def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

    def plugins = new Properties()

    def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
    if (pluginsFile.exists()) {

        pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
    }

    plugins.each { name, path ->
        def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
        include ":$name"
        project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
    }
```

Comment: Don't add this to the end of the default settings.gradle file - you can simply replace the whole file with this

Answer (score 3):

**My settings worked with the following versions.**

**pubspec.yaml**

firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5

  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5

I also added (**pubspec.yaml**) to silence the warnings.

  firebase_core: ^0.4.5

  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2

**build.gradle** (root dir)
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

**build.gradle** (app dir)
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 28

Then I added this at the bottom of **build.gradle**
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

The final thing is to run the ***Terminal*** command: 
$flutter packages get

After building the project - you wait 15 seconds and it will show a 
**"Congratulations, you've successfully added Firebase to your app!"** 
message on your Firebase Console.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

JUST add this to your settings.gradle file -

```
def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()

def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {

    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }

}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make the

> minSdkVersion 21

Answer (score 1):

In the addition to Peter's answer
I misplaces this line. The correct one is the bottom of the file

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the dependencies version is not matching. Please make sure your are using all latest versions of lib in your pubspec.yaml

You can refer the latest version of dependencies from
[PubDev](https://pub.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors:-

Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :cloud_fireenter code heres`enter code here`tore_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebas`enter code here`e_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

I resolved this by following process:-

Go to your app level gradle file and see there targetSdkVersion, if it has 16 or less then update to new latest version serching from this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element. It will be helpful.