# should i update settings.gradle when getting: Plugin project :location_web not found. Please update settings.gradle. but app still works?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the location package and when I start the app I get this message:

```
Plugin project :location_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
```

But everything works fine, what I found in this post: [Plugin project :location_web not found. Please update settings.gradle. How do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348554/plugin-project-location-web-not-found-please-update-settings-gradle-how-do-i) is that I should put this in my Settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

but this leads to my question my app works just fine and I have no clue what this code above does, so I am not really happy with putting something I don't understand my app.

**So could the above error message lead to some bigger problems in the future or can I just leave it?**

I reproduced this error message with the below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: GapNap()));

class GapNap extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('go to new screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class NewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewScreenState createState() => _NewScreenState();
}

class _NewScreenState extends State<NewScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: Text('jo')),
    );
  }


  Future<void> init() async {
    await getLocation();
    print(currentLocation.latitude);
  }

  final Location _location = Location();
  UserLocation currentLocation;

  Future<UserLocation> getLocation() async {
    try {
      var userLocation = await _location.getLocation();
      currentLocation = UserLocation(
          latitude: userLocation.latitude, longitude: userLocation.longitude);
      print('Location was succesfully found');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Coould not get the Location $e');
    }
    return currentLocation;
  }
}

class UserLocation {
  final double latitude;
  final double longitude;

  UserLocation({this.latitude, this.longitude});
}
```

Note: the message is shown when I start the app not when I am trying to get the location.
Output is:

```
Launching lib\ReproduceMyError.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Plugin project :location_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

Comment: I have same problem,but app works fine,i think it just warning,i have deployed the app to playstore,it works fine @tims

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

If the app still works, then the message is most likely just a warning. The cause of the issue could be from the plugin not being set up properly. Running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` usually solves the issue.