# Getting this exception while running flutter app for Android

Tags: flutter

Can anybody tell me what to do about these error. Everything is working fine when I run the same app on ios. For android I am getting the below exception. One error is plugin not found. Another one is some compilation issues.

```
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :cloud_firestore_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.


Note: /Users/daljitsingh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.7/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/Users/daljitsingh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerPlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/daljitsingh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_VIDEO_WITH_CAMERA = 2353;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
/Users/daljitsingh/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_VIDEO_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2354;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plugin project :firebase\_core\_web not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732409/plugin-project-firebase-core-web-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Update the Android Integration part of each of these plugins pub page: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth ...

Comment: I have already done the Android Integration part, but still its not working

Comment: run: flutter clean, then, close app on emulator and run flutter run -v

Comment: I solved the other image_picker error related to VisibleForTesting using the other version image_picker: ^0.6.0+9.

Comment: But I am still getting the plugin not found error. Unable to build apk